# Making binary file hold assets such as images, sounds, map files, etc

Tags: c#, vb.net, binaryfiles

Is it possible to create a binary file that can store game assets? I've looked all over stack overflow and the world wide web and I couldn't find anything. If you have no idea what the heck I'm talking about; I'm talking about creating binary files that act as asset libraries. An example for a game that does this would be Overwatch, World of Warcraft, GTA 5, SIMS 3, etc.

Comment: You can serialize any object including class with [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter)

Comment: Slai's right. [**Binary Serialization**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254617/Serialization-Part-I-Binary-Serialization) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Found a website from that spoke about turning pictures into bin files

[Washington.edu Turning Pictures into .bin](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse477/99sp/labs/pics.html)

From reading it seems the take the image convert them into ppm file then from there into a bin file.
Hope it points you in the right direction

Comment: How would I load it into a C# or VB.NET form?

Comment: check out if this would work for you http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/523483/Convertingplusanplusimageplusintoplusbinaryplusarr